# Leer argumentos de consola en un winmain (WINAPI)

Tags: windows, c++

Estoy modificando un pequeño el cual funciona solamente por consola y requiere de argumentos de consola. Pero ahora quería pasarlo a winmain(formulario) y obtener esos argumentos usando `GetCommandLine` y usarlos en un `WinMain` tal como hice en consola. El programa es el siguiente:

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    assert(argc > 1);

    // build command line

    wchar_t commandLine[MAX_PATH * 2];
    ::lstrcpyW(commandLine, argv[1]);
    if (argc > 2) {
        ::lstrcatW(commandLine, L" ");
        ::lstrcatW(commandLine, argv[2]);
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };

    // create the actual process with the debug flag to avoid an infinite loop

    BOOL bCreated = ::CreateProcessW(nullptr, commandLine, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, DEBUG_PROCESS, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi);
    if (bCreated) {
        WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
        ::GetModuleFileName(nullptr, path, MAX_PATH);
        *::wcsrchr(path, L'\\') = L'\0';
        ::wcscat_s(path, MAX_PATH, L"\\dllmain.Dll");

        // create a semaphore which count represents the main thread ID

        HANDLE hSemaphore = ::CreateSemaphore(nullptr, pi.dwThreadId - 1, pi.dwThreadId, L"InjectedMainThread");
        assert(hSemaphore);

        // duplicate in the injected process so the semaphore survives after the injected process goes away

        HANDLE hTarget = nullptr;
        ::DuplicateHandle(::GetCurrentProcess(), hSemaphore, pi.hProcess, &hTarget, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
        assert(hTarget);

        // allocate buffer for the DLL path name

        void* pPathBuffer = ::VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, nullptr, MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
        assert(pPathBuffer);

        // write the path

        SIZE_T written;
        ::WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, pPathBuffer, path, MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR), &written);

        // create a remote thread to load the DLL

        HANDLE hRemoteThread = ::CreateRemoteThread(pi.hProcess, nullptr, 0,
            (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "LoadLibraryW"),
            pPathBuffer, 0, nullptr);

        // allow the process to continue after this one exits

        ::DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(FALSE);

        // close handles (not really needed as we're existing)

        ::CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
        ::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        ::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        ::CloseHandle(hSemaphore);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pregunto porque necesito ayuda de un experto ya que puedo hacer la modificación pero no estoy muy seguro si este programa funcionará correctamente.

En este caso se le pasara dos argumentos y el assert no entiendo muy bien para que funciona ya que se supone que si no es mayor que uno(el numero de argumentos) el programa abortará.

Lo convierto a winmain:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpszCmdParam, 
                   int nCmdShow)
{
//int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    assert(argc > 1);

    // build command line

    wchar_t commandLine[MAX_PATH * 2];
    ::lstrcpyW(commandLine, argv[1]);
    if (argc > 2) {
        ::lstrcatW(commandLine, L" ");
        ::lstrcatW(commandLine, argv[2]);
    }

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };

    // create the actual process with the debug flag to avoid an infinite loop

    BOOL bCreated = ::CreateProcessW(nullptr, commandLine, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, DEBUG_PROCESS, nullptr, nullptr, &si, &pi);
    if (bCreated) {
        WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
        ::GetModuleFileName(nullptr, path, MAX_PATH);
        *::wcsrchr(path, L'\\') = L'\0';
        ::wcscat_s(path, MAX_PATH, L"\\Injected.Dll");

        // create a semaphore which count represents the main thread ID

        HANDLE hSemaphore = ::CreateSemaphore(nullptr, pi.dwThreadId - 1, pi.dwThreadId, L"InjectedMainThread");
        assert(hSemaphore);

        // duplicate in the injected process so the semaphore survives after the injected process goes away

        HANDLE hTarget = nullptr;
        ::DuplicateHandle(::GetCurrentProcess(), hSemaphore, pi.hProcess, &hTarget, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
        assert(hTarget);

        // allocate buffer for the DLL path name

        void* pPathBuffer = ::VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, nullptr, MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
        assert(pPathBuffer);

        // write the path

        SIZE_T written;
        ::WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, pPathBuffer, path, MAX_PATH * sizeof(WCHAR), &written);

        // create a remote thread to load the DLL

        HANDLE hRemoteThread = ::CreateRemoteThread(pi.hProcess, nullptr, 0,
            (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)::GetProcAddress(::GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32"), "LoadLibraryW"),
            pPathBuffer, 0, nullptr);

        // allow the process to continue after this one exits

        ::DebugSetProcessKillOnExit(FALSE);

        // close handles (not really needed as we're existing)

        //::CloseHandle(hRemoteThread);
        //::CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        //::CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        //::CloseHandle(hSemaphore);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pero me devuelve los siguientes errores obviamente por los argumentos que nos los puse tengo que leerlos.. usando getcommandline a partir de `lpszCmdParam`, pero no se muy bien como, errores:

```
C2065: 'argc': undeclared identifier 
C2065: 'argv': undeclared identifier 
C2660: 'lstrcpyW': function does not take 1 arguments 
C2065: 'argc': undeclared identifier 
C2065: 'argv': undeclared identifier 
C2660: 'lstrcatW': function does not take 1 arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** puedo confirmalo (no uso windows), pero, dada la fuente, creo que es correcto.

A la función `WinMain( )`, la línea de órdenes le llega a través de su argumento `lpszCmdParam`; para convertirla en una *arreglo* similar a `argv`, se puede usar la función [`CommandLineToArgvW( )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/bb776391(v=vs.85).aspx)

En el ejemplo propuesto, sería mas o menos así:

Modificar lo siguiente:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, ... ) {
```

Lo convertimos en

```
 int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
```

Además, hacemos lo siguiente:

```
char cmd[] = "taskmgr.exe" ; // note: non-const (writeable array)
HANDLE thread = nullptr ;
auto myProc=Startpausedprocess( cmd, std::addressof(thread) ) ;

// AÑADIMOS ESTO

int argv; // <- Añadir esto.
wchar_t **argv; // <- Y esto también.

argv = CommandLineToArgvW( pCmdLine, &argc );
```

A partir de ese momento, `argv[]` será *equivalente* al código original, **excepto** por una cosa: **HAY QUE CAMBIAR TODOS LOS ÍNDICES POR UNO MENOS**.

Es decir, si vemos, en el código original, `argv[1]`, **tenemos que cambiarlo** por `argv[0]`. Y así **en todos los casos**.

Esto es debido a que, en el valor retornado por `CommandLineToArgvW( )`, **se ha omitido la ruta al ejecutable**; lo que sería `argv[0]`.

Comment: @OmarOmar `argc` es establecido al llamar a `CommandLineToArgvW( )`. Fíjate que le paso como 2º argumento un *puntero* a `argc`. La propia función lo cambia, para que se ajuste al número de argumentos reales.

Comment: @OmarOmar el *prototipo* real de `commandline` **es** `wchar_t **CommandLineToArgvW( wchar_t *, int * );`. En el código que he puesto, la llamo como `argv = CommandLineToArgW( pCmdLine, &argc )`; La llamo con un puntero a cadena y con un puntero a entero.

Comment: Funciono correctamente muchas gracias genio!

Comment: @OmarOmar Un placer :-) 